# R: Adjusting exploratory variable's distribution to known (non-normal) distribution

Tags: r, distributions, modeling, data-transformation

My team is studying ways to improve pharmacy chain sales by using drug coupons. Each row in our dataset, which is just a 10,000-row sample that hopefully reflects the U.S. population --- represents a transaction at a pharmacy's counter. We hope to understand how explanatory variables such as drug price *E*, along with others such as the kind of illness that a patient has or his level of insurance coverage, could enhance the effectiveness of drug coupons at reducing the probability *R* that people return a bought item.

It is necessary for the sample and population to have similar distribution of *E* to ensure validity of statistical models linking it to *R*.  Unfortunately, there is a significant discrepancy between the frequency distributions of *E* in the U.S. population and in the sample (see summary below). In particular, a normal distribution does not seem to describe well the population distribution.

[image: Population vs Sample Distributions of E]

What are good things to do in *R* to make the sample's *E*-distribution more akin to the population's, hopefully to match it? I have tried filtering off sample data with low *E* values to no avail. At the same time, I am not quite sure which transformations to use since most of the common transformations attempt to fit data to a normal distribution --- which does not seem applicable here.

I myself think that transformations (possibly including weightings) of E are permissible, deletion of rows borderline acceptable, and creation of new rows forbidden --- but I would appreciate any input on what operations are usually considered permissible in contexts similar to mine.

Thanks for your input.

Best,

PDE

Comment: Could you explain why you want to make your sample distribution match the population distribution and clarify what operations on the sample data you would permit in order to make this match come about?

Comment: The explanatory variable _E_ is a price that affects the probability _R_ that people return a bought item. I myself think that transformations of _E_ are permissible, deletion of rows borderline acceptable, and creation of new rows forbidden --- but I would appreciate any input on what operations are usually considered permissible in contexts similar to mine.

Comment: I appreciate that you have told us what $E$ is--but you still have not revealed what you hope such transformations or other operations on the data are intended to achieve.  What is "permissible" will depend fundamentally on those objectives.  Exactly what analyses will be performed with $E$? Why do you think they will be improved by changing $E$ or deleting some of the data?

Comment: @whuber: Each row in our dataset reflects a transaction at the counter of a major US pharmacy. My team is studying ways to improve pharmacy chain sales by using drug coupons. We hope to understand how variables such as drug price (_E_) --- along with other explanatory variables such as the kind of illness that a patient has or his level of insurance coverage --- could enhance the effectiveness of drug coupons.

Comment: Thank you--that's useful information that I hope you will include in an edit to your question.

Comment: @whuber: My post now reflects your suggested edits.

Comment: Search " direct standardization"  or "indirect standardization"in Epidemiology

Comment: @DeepNorth: Thanks for your help. How do the weighted averages output by (in)direct standardization interplay with my team's need to match our sample's data distribution to that of the U.S. population? We seem to need to modify our data, whereas both standardizations accept the data as they are and merely work around a problem that does not appear to apply here. Please correct or complete my understanding if needed.

Comment: I'm still at a loss to understand why your team thinks it needs to match distributions.  That is not necessary for achieving the objectives you have described in the comments.  In fact, it seems that any effort to make the sample distribution match the target distribution would either seriously distort the data or lose a large portion of the information in it.

Comment: @whuber: I completely agree with you. It is unfortunately the case that my boss thinks this is how it must be done. I am trying to address this issue by, on one hand, finding a sample that fits the population distribution better and, on the other hand, randomly deleting low-_E_ rows and duplicating higher-_E_ ones. Any other advice?